# can someone help me to code this exercise

Tags: python

i need to ask the user for five initials and then store them in a dictionary as keys
and store last names as values, i've got this at this moment

```
  dicts = {}
  keys = range(5)
  values = ["Marta", "Avila", "Torres", "Lujan", "Ochoa"]
  for i in keys:
      dicts[i] = values[i]
  print(dicts)
```

this code, prints:

{0: 'Marta', 1: 'Avila', 2: 'Torres', 3: 'Lujan', 4: 'Ochoa'}

and this is the result i want:

{M: 'Marta', A: 'Avila', T: 'Torres', L: 'Lujan', O: 'Ochoa'}

Comment: You're using numbers for the keys, if you want the letters as keys you need to build your key list accordingly, like `keys=[i[0] for i in values]`

Comment: Notice you are setting the keys to `range(5)` which is 0-4

Answer (score 2):

This should fix it:

```py
dicts = {}
values = ["Marta", "Avila", "Torres", "Lujan", "Ochoa"]

for name in values:
    dicts[name[0]] = name

print(dicts)
```

Comment: Quick explanation: `name[0]` gets the first letter of the name.

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: Just making sure the OP understands your solution.

Comment: Oh! I read it as quick question.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, the i variable is the number of the value that it is at, so it shows as a number. Try using something else that will return the first letter in the string, instead of the string's index. nerveless child has given you the correct code, and I have explained the issue, so you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one liner

a= dict(zip(values[0], values))